# How to solve $\int_{0}^{2n}f(x)\,dx$ where $f(x)=\max\{|x|,|x-1|,|x-2|,...,|x-2n|\}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: integration

> **Q**. Define a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\max\{|x|,|x-1|,|x-2|,...,|x-2n|\}$ where $n$ is a fixed natural number. Then $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2n}f(x)\,dx$ is ?

My attempt:

[image]

From graph I found out that for all $x<2n,f(x)=|x-2n|$

Therefore the required integral must be the area of the triangle enclosed by $x=0,y=0$ and $y=|x-2n|$ which is equal to $2n^2$.

But the answer given in the book is $3n^2$

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}|x-2n|&x\lt n\\|x|&n\le x\le 2n\end{cases}$$

which gives
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}2n-x&x\lt n\\x&n\le x\le 2n\end{cases}$$

Thus,
$$\int_0^{2n}f(x)dx=\int_0^n(2n-x)dx+\int_n^{2n}xdx=2nx-\frac{x^2}{2}\biggr\rvert_{0}^{n}+\frac{x^2}{2}\biggr\rvert_{n}^{2n}=2n^2-\frac{n^2}{2}+2n^2-\frac{n^2}{2}=3n^2$$